# How to search a string for different tenses?

Tags: forms, lucene.net, morphological-analysis

I can use Stemmers, Filters etc. No problem.

But what about this case, for example the source text contains the phrase:

The fox made a jump.

User has entered: fox AND make
Results = 0;

The question is how to process irregular forms of words?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't that many irregular verbs.  Get a list of the most common ones like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs) and use it to do a find/replace in your query string to replace "make" with ("make" OR "made") before submitting.